# Unable to fetch response from QnAMaker for some inputs

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-qna-maker

When tested in `QnaMaker` itself, inputs `analyst report` and `analyst reports` give me the response. However, the call in our bot solution does not give
response for `analyst reports` - it only gives response for `analyst report`. The error returned is

> Sequence contains no elements

Call to `QnaMaker`:

```
QueryResult[] result = null;
try
{
    result = await botServices.QnaServices[FAQQnAMakerKey].GetAnswersAsync(dc.Context);
}
catch { /* ... */ }
```

The expected output is the same as one tested in `QnaMaker` - same response for `analyst report` and `analyst reports`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing 'analyst report' and 'analyst reports' gets different scores and maybe one gets filtered out by bot framework.

the `QnAMaker` class takes an `QnAMakerOptions` object in the constructor which defaults to `null`, but I'm unsure about what the `QnAMakerOptions.ScoreThreshold` defaults to. You could try to specify this to 0 to make sure you'll get any responses.

```
var qnaMaker = new QnAMaker(new QnAMakerEndpoint
    {
      KnowledgeBaseId = _configuration["QnAKnowledgebaseId"],
      EndpointKey = _configuration["QnAEndpointKey"],
      Host = _configuration["QnAEndpointHostName"]
    },
    new QnAMakerOptions
    {
      Top = 3,
      Timeout = 10000,
      ScoreThreshold = 0F
    },
    httpClient);
```

Alternatively you can just add the options to the function call to `GetAnswerAsync()`

```
var response = await qnaMaker.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext, new QnAMakerOptions
    {
      Top = 3,
      Timeout = 10000,
      ScoreThreshold = 0F
    }
    );
```

Comment: Hi @Thyselius , I tried adding the QnaMakerOptions like you said but it did not help.

Comment: Hey @SM, have you tried to republish your knowledge base after training it? I'm not sure on how QnAMaker works but it's worth a try :)

Comment: yes, I tried doing that- it did not help. I will create a model class to make a call to the Qnamaker

Comment: @SM Just tried it myself and you do not need to publish for the new training to work, found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/confidence-score#confidence-score-differences) which you might find interesting as it seems this might just be a "feature" from MS.